# HTML SVG reuse a group <g> with <use> and change attributes of inner elements individually for each instance

Tags: javascript, html, svg, code-reuse

So i'd like to reuse a grouped svg shape and change one attribute of one of the elements inside of the group individually for each instance.
The following simplified example creates a second circle with a rectangle inside. I now want to change the "width" attribute of the "my-rect" rectangle individually for each of the shapes with javascript. Using the id "my-rect" will change the width of both rectangles, but I want to change only one.

My goal (if my approach is nonsense): I have to draw multiple of these shapes and the only thing that differs is the position and the width of the rectangle.

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <a transform="translate(110,110)">
    <g id="my-group">
      <g>
        <circle r="100" fill="#0000BF" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.8"></circle>
      </g>
      <g>
        <rect id="my-rect" y="-50" height="100" x="-50" width="50">
        </rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </a>
  <use xlink:href="#my-group" x="340" y="110"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of trickery, it is possible. You have to take advantage of CSS inheritance to get some property value inside a shadow element. In this case, it will be custom variables that will be used to scale and position the rectangle.

The markup has to be rewritten a bit for this. First, you write your group inside a `<defs>` element, making it a template for reuse, but not rendered by itself. Second, the rectangle is placed inside a nested `<svg overflow="visible">` element. Giving this element the x/y coordinates and leaving them at 0 for the `<rect>` element makes it easier to track where the left side of the rectangle will end up after a transforming operation.

Now the width change of the rect is achieved with a `scaleX()` transformation plus a `translate()` for the position. This **must be in CSS transform syntax**. Using a `transform` attribute would not work (yet). Therefore, we also need a `transform-origin` property, set to the left side of the enclosing `<svg>` element.

Instead of writing a concrete value for the scaling, the value is expressed as a variable with the default value 1: `var(--scale, 1)`; same for the positional values. The value for the variable is set in a `style` attribute for each `<use>` element separately: `style="--scale:2;--posX:20px; --posY:-10px"`. Note the need for writing `px` units!

```css
#my-rect {
    transform-origin: left top;
    transform: translate(var(--posX, 0), var(--posY, 0)) scaleX(var(--scale, 1));
}
```

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <defs>
    <g id="my-group">
      <g>
        <circle r="100" fill="#0000BF" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="0.8"></circle>
      </g>
      <svg x="-50" y="-50" overflow="visible">
        <rect id="my-rect" height="100" width="50">
        </rect>
      </svg>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#my-group" x="110" y="110" style="--scale:1"/>
  <use xlink:href="#my-group" x="340" y="110" style="--scale:2;--posX:20px; --posY:-10px"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice! I learned something new. You can also replace that `<svg x="-50" y="-50" overflow="visible">` with a `<g transform="translate(-50 -50)">` if you don't like nesting SVGs.

Comment: Thank you, can this also work with height? My naive approach using ScaleY did not work.

Comment: I used your example and just switchend the X with the Y. After your comment I tried both variations you mentioned, but both resulted in the same result: The rectangle moves up or down while changing its height (edited)

Comment: I found my error: `transform-origin: left` leaves the y origin at `center`, so it has to be `transform-origin: left top` to work.

Answer (score 6):

Sean said:

> If the Web Components Custom Elements gets expanded to the SVG namespace,
> more complex reuse will be possible

Which is true, you can't make **custom SVG** elements (yet).

But you can make a native JavaScript Web Component (JSWC) that **generates** SVG:

```js
customElements.define("rect-in-circle", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    const a = x => this.getAttribute(x);
    this.innerHTML=`<svg viewBox="-100 -100 100 100">`+
                   `<g transform="translate(-50 -50)">`+
                     `<circle r="50" fill="#123456AB"/>`+
                     `<rect y="${a("y")}" height="${a("height")}"`+
                           `x="${a("x")}"  width="${a("width" )}"/>`+
                   `</g></svg>`
  }
});
```

```css
svg{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  fill:green;
}
```

```html
<rect-in-circle x=-10 y=-10 width=20 height=20></rect-in-circle>
<rect-in-circle x=-40 y=-20 width=10 height=40></rect-in-circle>
<rect-in-circle x= 10 y= 20 width=30 height= 5></rect-in-circle>
```

Custom Elements for SVG are a modern solution to many oldskool SVG hacks

#### Update

If OP wants **one** SVG with circles, we can use shadowDOM and the fact that elements inside lightDOM are not displayed. We can even use *undefined* `<rect>` elements (in the HTML namespace) so we can easily inject them in the SVG string.

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("rects-in-circles", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const rects = [...this.children];
        const width = rects.length * 100;
        this.attachShadow({
          mode: "open"
        }).innerHTML = `<svg viewBox='0 0 ${width} 100'>` + 
          rects.map((rect, idx) => `<g transform='translate(${50+100*idx} 50)'>` +
          `<circle r='50' fill='green'/>` +
          rect.outerHTML +
          `</g>`) + "</svg>";

      })
    }
  });

</script>

<rects-in-circles>
  <rect x=-10 y=-10 width=20 height=20></rect>
  <rect x=-40 y=-20 width=10 height=40></rect>
  <rect x=10 y=20 width=30 height=5></rect>
  <rect x=-40 y=-40 width=50 height=50></rect>
</rects-in-circles>
```

`(my)` Related StackOverflow answers: [Custom Elements and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22Custom-Elements-SVG%22&shadowDOM)

Comment: You won't be able to use that custom element inside of an SVG though, like the question requests.

Comment: Correct. Custom Elements don't work within the SVG Namespace, as you said. OP wants a circle with a dynamic rect. If he wants **3** circles in **one** SVG he has to adapt the Custom Element to output **one** SVG with 3 circles.

Comment: Thanks that also looked promising, but the "change width with javascript" (after it has already been rendered) part is missing here. At least I don't know how it would work with this approach. Therefore I accepted ccprog's answer.

Comment: Since we can use undefined elements in html. Is there any workaround to have <rect> elements to be custom elements as well ? Like for example <svg-container><custompath size=4  /></svg-container> trying to simulate <use> tag but with custom attributes. The purpose is to save most html chars for page load and parsing of my big svg images

Comment: The biggest limitation is: you can only create Custom Elements in the HTML Namespace (``extend HTMLElement)``). You can not create SVG (Namespaced) Custom Elements. ``custompath`` must be written as ``custom-path`` to be a valid CE name. For more inspiration see: [DEV.to post, using Unknown Elements](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c)

Comment: I actually managed to come up with something after editing your pie-chart webComponent, here's my fork: https://jsfiddle.net/kvscz8aw/
Thanks for your big contributions on these topics! Hopefully one day we will be able to extend SVGElement as well :)

Comment: Anyway I don't think there's any advantages in the performance of the svg render like the <use> tag so we still have to wait for the spec to update

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. The `use` element creates a [`closed shadow root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), which means its contents are inaccessible to JS. While you can set attributes of instances of the reused element individually (if they haven't been set on the original element) you won't be able to affect elements that are children of the reused element.

An alternative approach would be to reuse the rectangle and circle elements directly, and placing them in a new group.

Comment: If the Web Components Custom Elements gets expanded to the SVG namespace, more complex reuse will be possible: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/634

Answer (score 0):

The `getAttribute` method didn't work for me but this worked:

```
customElements.define("source-link", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['href'];
    }

    get href() {
        return this.getAttribute('href');
    }

    set href(val) {
        if (val) {
            this.setAttribute('href', val);
        } else {
            this.removeAttribute('href');
        }
    }
    connectedCallback(){
        this.innerHTML= '<a href="' + this.href + '" target="_blank" title="source"><svg fill="#37f" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="16"><g><path d="M488.727,0H302.545c-12.853,0-23.273,10.42-23.273,23.273c0,12.853,10.42,23.273,23.273,23.273h129.997L192.999,286.09    c-9.089,9.089-9.089,23.823,0,32.912c4.543,4.544,10.499,6.816,16.455,6.816c5.956,0,11.913-2.271,16.457-6.817L465.455,79.458    v129.997c0,12.853,10.42,23.273,23.273,23.273c12.853,0,23.273-10.42,23.273-23.273V23.273C512,10.42,501.58,0,488.727,0z"/></g><g><path d="M395.636,232.727c-12.853,0-23.273,10.42-23.273,23.273v209.455H46.545V139.636H256c12.853,0,23.273-10.42,23.273-23.273    S268.853,93.091,256,93.091H23.273C10.42,93.091,0,103.511,0,116.364v372.364C0,501.58,10.42,512,23.273,512h372.364    c12.853,0,23.273-10.42,23.273-23.273V256C418.909,243.147,408.489,232.727,395.636,232.727z"/></g></svg></a>';
    }
});
```

**Usage**:

```
<source-link href="//google.com"></source-link>
```

[Source :D](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements)